# how can i get the value of the specific column of a table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

How can i read the value from every row of a specific column?

I have a `table` shown here [Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F8vM.jpg), i want to get the model name from the "Model" `column` and i have a `database` and "SELECT" query behind depending on the "Model" that is shown, it will show the quantity of the "Model" can someone help me?

here is a sample code of my .cs

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gv1.Rows)
        {

            for(int i = 0; i<gv1.Columns.Count;i++)
            {
                string model = row.Cells[i].Text;
                string quan = row.Cells[3].Text;
                string ams = row.Cells[4].Text;

            }
        }
```

Note:-

- data shown in the table are already in the database.
- i have 2 seperate View tables for the Models and the Quantity.

Comment: So what specifically are you having issues with?

Comment: Don't need of `for` loop, Simply access the values of cell by using static index's like `row.Cells[0].Text`,`row.Cells[1].Text`...

Comment: but i want to display the Quantity of every item based on the Model column

Comment: BugFinder ; i want to get the value of a specific data inside a column, to get the data i can get the Quantity of that data from the database. and i will show the quantity per row

Comment: that doesnt really explain it.. the select query is where you get the right data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand well what you want it's clearly not the best approach, but i will try to help you.
In my opinion you have to get the quantity value before the display of your dataTable, inside this DataTable, but anyway i think this is the type of code that you requested :

```
//My dataTable to test , with 3 columns
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Model");
        dt.Columns.Add("Other");
        dt.Columns.Add("QuantityFromDB");

        //Add some  test data in my dataTable
        for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = i*2+"";
            dr[1] = "XX data XX";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

     //Foreach row in your datatable ( your data )
    for(int y=0;y<dt.Rows.Count;y++)
        {
            //Get the value of the current "Model" Column value
            string currentModel = dt.Rows[y]["Model"].ToString();

            //make your request in the db to get the quantity
            int quantityfromdb = 50; //REQUEST

            //Update the value of the QuantityFromDB column for this model row
            dt.Rows[y]["QuantityFromDB"] = quantityfromdb;
        }
```

You read the value of a specific row, and edit the value of it's other column.

EDIT :

If you want to work directly on the gridview, you can moove your code in the row_databound event of your gridview.
See doc : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx